# cannot rdp to Ubuntu18 hyper-v Quick start

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, hyper-v

There is a issue with xrdp that is not able to paste a password https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/816 so I gave my ubuntu hyper-v image a fixed ip so I can connect using regular remote desktop so the password can saved and passed in. But when I try to connect to my ubuntu hyper-v image already running  xrdp, I am not able to. Connection denied. I log in using the Hyper-V manager to go check if it is listening on port 3389.

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " | grep ":3389"
```

The above returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Hyper-V Quick start overrides the port to use a vsock which makes it work with Hyper-V Manager but it is not compatible with regular RDP.

/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

```
port=3389
; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
use_vsock=true
```

Save a checkpoint on the HyperV manager just in case you lose connectivity. Change the above from `true` to `false`, save then restart VM. (I tried just restaring the xrdp agen `sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart` but this left me with a black screen on the new session so I had to restart anyway)

The downside to this is that you will no longer be able to connect from the Hyper-V manager. The upside is that you will not have to type in your password every time.